# Exclude .cs from project through code? (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#

I need to exclude .cs files from project through code, for example with T4 template. I know that you can modify the .csproj file, but this doesn't work properly if the project is opened with Visual Studio, so is there any way to exclude/add .cs files through code(for example, with T4 templates)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you change the Build action of CS file to none, or anything other than Compile, it wont compile.

Comment: I want to compile or not depend on the user.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [build configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx) - set Build action to none for one build configuration

Comment: but i want to add a build configuration through code(for example, with T4 templates)